# Feature request: add marvosym package to our MathJax set (for celestial body symbols)

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

Shameless copy from [SF.'s question on Space Meta](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/feature-request-add-marvosym-package-to-our-mathjax-set-for-celestial-body-sym):

`\usepackage{marvosym}` allows you to write `M_\Sun` or `r_\Earth` to have variables annotated with celestial body symbols. It would be surely nice to have in the mark-up.

The list of planet symbols included is as follows:

> `\Sun \Moon \Mercury \Venus \Mars \Jupiter \Saturn \Uranus \Neptune \Pluto \Earth`

Would it be much trouble to include this package in our set, so that this would work?:

$M_\Sun = 1.989e30 kg$